# Call another python file using Qt Designer

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyside, qt-designer

I usually use `call("/home/"+userName+"/./a.py", shell=True)` to call another python file and this works just fine for me. But now as I am using Qt Designer for creating UI I want to call a python file when one of my tree item gets activated. I could not find any way to call python files with QtDesigners IDE.

[image: Program looks like this]

I am using Ubuntu ,Python and Qt Designer. 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Has this anything to do with calling python files, or is it just about how to assign some action to the menu? Also, don't know Qt Designer, but I assume this is for creating the GUI only. To add an action, show us the code.

Comment: Someone who has worked with Qt-Designer will know this surely.. I am working with this for the first time and I am able to build UI but cant add functionality to the controls.. but I am adding the code with the question for better understanding.

Comment: sorry I was unable to add the code.. The code is quiet big and when I try to add the code the layout just breaks down..

Comment: Qt Designer is not an IDE.